# Asp.net 5 rc1-final ReflectionTypeLoadException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, web-deployment, asp.net-core-mvc

I have developed asp.net 5 application. I try to make deployment to IIS on a server. I think i did everythinhg correctly but i get this exception. I checked windows event logs and iis event logs too and found nothing.

[Exception Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGUlK.png)

Can someone help me ? I really need to make this site work ?

Comment: Did you enable the httpPlatform logs and check those ... You can enable them from your web.config file.

Comment: i find the solution, i used my old class library although i wrapped it and add reference to o project after i publish it  still  throws exception than i changed my class libary to nuget class library and problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
I used my old class library although I wrapped it and add reference to o project. After I published it it still throws exception. Than I changed my class libary to nuget class library and the problem was solved